# How to supply a flying club with MOGAS?

Tags: fuel, refueling, fbo

I've noticed that there are [very few airports that serve MOGAS](http://www.flyunleaded.com/airports.php). If I wanted to start a flying club with a MOGAS powered airplane, but there wasn't an FBO nearby that served MOGAS how would I go about it?

- Is it worth it to an FBO to offer MOGAS?
- Should I have the FC members supply their own gas with a couple of [personal fuel stations](http://www.northerntool.com/shop/tools/product_200584598_200584598?utm_source=CSE&utm_medium=Google&utm_campaign=Fuel%20Transfer%20%2B%20Lubrication%20%3E%20Fuel%20Caddies&utm_content=29578&ci_src=17588969&ci_sku=29578&gclid=CMaSpOvDxsUCFdOQHwodNVYAqg) like the one pictured below? (anyone have any experience with this method?)

[image: Personal Fuel Station]

**Update:** Tried to reword questions to make it less business & more "how-to".

Comment: while related to aviation, the question seems to focus on a business logistics problem.

Answer (score 2):

The FC I used to belong to had it's own fuel trailer (custom-built with dual double-walled, insulated cryogenic 100-gallon tanks, a manually-operated fuel pump, a totalizer, a delivery hose and nozzle, and appropriate grounding cables.  Excluding the cost of the basic flat-bed trailer itself (one of the FC members loaned it to the club) we had less than $1500 invested in the outfit - including inspection and trailer licensing fees.

Considering we would be carrying 200 gallons of MOGAS on public highways we had to be VERY careful as to WHEN we were ON the highways (basically very late at night, and we drove on lightly-used roads/streets) - and we had to have insurance commensurate with the commodity we were carrying.  We used this trailer for several years - without any incident(s) - but, in the end, we all felt un-easy about doing so and eventually we abandoned the idea and reverted to using hand-carried gas cans.

The FC disbanded years ago and I don't know what ever happened to the fuel rig - I believe it went back to the FC member who built it in the first place (his materials costs and his labor bought him a club membership, whereas the rest of us had to ante up actual cash to help buy the airplane the FC bought.)

Ahhh, the good ol' days....